# Good word for "a request that can't be refused"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a good word for describing **"a request that cannot be refused"**? For example, the context I'm thinking about is a situation where your boss "requests" that you work overtime one day, but it's pretty clear that it's a request that can't be refused (or, at the very least, it's something you believe you can't say no to).

I guess we could say "irrefusable"? But I'm not sure if that's even the right word, and I'm wondering if anyone can think of a better word for this.

Comment: Have you looked up 'irrefusable'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, "irrefusable" means "impossible to refuse" (the [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/irrefusable)). And it's possible to refuse a request (the [Oxford Collocation Dictionary](http://www.freecollocation.com/search?word=request)). So, technically, if it's impossible for you to refuse a request, the request is irrefusable.

It can also be called an *[I-won't-take-no-for-an-answer](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/won-t-take-no-for-an-answer)* kind of request.

Comment: thanks, i think you're right that irrefusable probably is the best choice for this

Answer (score 0):

> Your boss compels you to work overtime, a request that can't be
>   refused if you hope to keep your job.

**compel**

> 1. To force (a person) to do something; drive or constrain:
> 2. To necessitate or require, as by force of circumstance; demand:
> 3. To exert a strong, irresistible force on; sway:

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's a request that you are (or feel) [**obliged**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obliged) to fulfill.

> to constrain by physical, moral, or legal force or by the exigencies of circumstance · *obliged* to find a job · felt *obliged* to share it with her
>
> Her job *obliges* her to work overtime and on weekends.

Comment: How about "a Godfather request", from the famous line in the Godfather movie, "...make him an offer he can't refuse".

Answer (score 0):

I would call that a **peremptory** request.

[Oxford's Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/peremptory):

> *peremptory* adj
>
> (especially of somebody’s manner or behaviour) expecting to be obeyed immediately and without questioning or refusing

Answer (score 0):

Putting [scare quote](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scare-quotes)s around "voluntary" may work in some contexts.

> noun [ plural ]
>
> Quotation marks (= the symbols “ ” or ‘ ’ ) that are sometimes put
> around a word or phrase in a written sentence in order to show that
> the word is being used in a special way or in a way that may not be
> correct or true.

For example:

Following the prank, Nigel was invited to a "voluntary" meeting with Human Resources.

Comment: Along this vein, the term "voluntold" has been steadily gaining popularity, though it's definitely slang/informal.

Answer (score -1):

Among the lists of synonyms for 'compulsory / obligatory' and related words, the only one I've found that I'd consider anywhere near suitable for *[the giving of] 'not-quite-a-direct' order* is

**coercion**

which [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/coercion) defines rather amusingly as

> the use of force to persuade someone to do something that they are
>   unwilling to do

(the juxtaposition of 'force' and 'persuade' seems very odd).

[RHK Webster's](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/coerce) gives the senses (for the verb; the noun's definition is derived)

> *coerce* v.t.
>
> 1. to compel by force or intimidation: to coerce someone into signing a document.
> 2. to bring about through force; exact: to coerce obedience.
> 3. to dominate or control, esp. by exploiting fear, anxiety, etc.

while [Collins](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/coerce) has

> *coerce* vb (tr)
>
> to compel or restrain by force or authority without regard to
>   individual wishes or desires

So, picking among the definitions, '[referring to an authority] to control, even compel, by exploiting fear of repercussions that could be taken by the authority' is one valid sense.